# How to Learn Pi

Tags: discussion

[What are the basics needed to learn Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57203/what-are-the-basics-needed-to-learn-raspberry-pi)

This is a nice question and currently is on the way to being closed for being to broad. But I think we should keep it open and make the answer into a Wiki?

@Ghanima already started with some nice, close to this community links.

But I am sure we can expand on this. There are many free ebooks and other resource people can benefit from , when searching for terms like this from the giant indexers of the web.

Comment: If it stays open it should have an intro that describes the problem with the question (i.e. does that mean learn Linux, electronics, a specific programming language etc.). Then subsections that cover the various meanings the original question may encompass - this would also provide a little structure to what could be an enormous list.

Comment: There are numerous web sites which can help you learn Python.  I suggest you start by searching for example code.  Then, as you have specific questions about syntax, utilize Google to find the answers.

Comment: I don't need to learn yet another programming language - Thanks :D This was for the benefit of new users looking how to start to useing the Pi - Landing here and asking a broad question.. that instead maybe Google could index if we had a nice Wiki for entry point questions like this.. that was all . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think I flipped a coin - close as too broad or try to give an answer. Being more reluctant over mod-hammer closing and leaning to the Mr Robillard school of moderation I went with *answer*.

If we - that is the community - decide to keep the question open I will gladly gift the answer to community wiki in the sense ppumkin suggested.

Comment: I too hope the question stays open, as a Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

As a newcomer to both Rpi3 and the community itself, I look at this question with two different feelings.

The education-hungry side of myself loves a list of resources because I want to also learn and discover new resources. Additionally, I like neat and compact repositories. These are great things to find.

The other side of myself also understands these become canonical in nature, open off topic debates about why one is better or worse because of XYZ, and need constant update as the resources change.

I think keeping how the SE Q&A system works in mind is a determining factor here. What is the impact in allowing the question after the answer changes and are 'we' as a community going to constantly and consistently update the answer - or - do we forget duplicate questions in this specific arena (no, I wouldn't think so).

I'd feel better if it did close. Disappointing as it may be to many, the answers to the question are opinion based and would be very difficult work with.

I'd propose handling this type of question like I try and do on Arqade when someone asks about pirated software, and that is to direct them simply to the official source to discover an endorsed list of resources, and letting that question stand, but closing all others a duplicates. It removes the answer as an opinion, and establishes the questions in the system to be searchable at any time.

That's just my opinion though.

Comment: I am also new I have learned alot on here. I don't mind a broad question like Shawn Gordon says it can be exciting to go look up, share and learn too. However I don't answer very many broad question as I have little experience so I can't recommend  or help as well as more experienced users.